# Unable to Resolve Identifier constexpr

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I'm teaching myself C++ with the textbook 'Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition)' and have come across a problem while trying to run an example problem. The line I'm supposed to input is

```
    constexpr int max = 17;
```

but I am getting an error: "Unable to resolve identifier constexpr", but I have no idea why because I have the necessary header file (specific to the textbook, downloaded from www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h ) All the other programs I've tried have worked just fine...
Other useful info:
-Using Netbeans (C++ Version)
-Using Windows 8
-Using Cygwin
-Not an expert.

Comment: Upgrade your compiler (or add an option to enable C++11: g++ -std=c++11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr` is a new feature of C++11. You need a C++11 capable compiler (like g++4.8) and have to enable the C++11 extensions when you compile a program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test
```

Comment: How do I enable C++11 extensions?

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to your compiler flags/otions.

Comment: Uhh yeah... I have no idea where Cygwin's options are. I searched for it and nothing came up. (himt, I'm a complete noob to this)\

Comment: I dont know the Netbeans IDE but in its Compiler settings there should be an option to enable C++11

EDIT:
Project Properties > Build > C++ Compiler >

Compilation Line > Additional Options
 set it to: -std=c++11